# sudo apt-get update and adding a repository error

Tags: apt, updates, ppa

Whenever I sudo apt-get update I get an error. Here are the errors from the log:

```
  Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu eoan Release 
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] 

  Err:14
  http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu eoan Release     
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] 

 Err:15
  http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu eoan Release       
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80] 

  E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu 
  eoan Release' does not have a Release file. 

  N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
  therefore disabled by default. 

  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user 
  configuration details. 

  E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome-terminator/ppa/ubuntu 
  eoan Release' does not have a Release file. 

  N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is 
  therefore disabled by default. 

  N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user
  configuration details.  

  E: The repository
  'http://ppa.launchpad.net/pipelight/stable/ubuntu eoan Release' does
  not have a Release file.  

  N: Updating from such a repository can't be
  done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.  

  N: See
  apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration
  details.
```

also when I try for example `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:openrazer/daily`
or adding any other repository, I get a similar error

Can someone help me solve this? there are some answers over the internet, but I'm a beginner, so I can't understand how to fix my specific problem and not similar problems... thanks in advance!

Comment: @Kulfy actually no... I can't understand what I should do, which ppa I should refer in my specific situation :/

Comment: Remove all the ppas that are 'not found' in the list of errors in your question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!

You have a bunch of [Personal Package Archives](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+ppas) in your installation which are invalid/no longer valid. You'll have to remove the PPA for each error thrown by `apt`. You can do this as follows:

For

```
 Err:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ehoover/compholio/ubuntu eoan Release 404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.95.83 80]
```

the PPA name is `ehoover/compholio`. You'll have to remove this PPA. This can be achieved in two ways.

## Method 1

To remove PPA's you need to install `ppa-purge` (or see Method 2, if you don't want to install any additional packages).

```
$ sudo apt-get install ppa-purge
```

You can remove this PPA by running the command

```
$ sudo ppa-purge ppa:ehoover/compholio
```

Likewise, run the command for each error line encountered. A complete list for your case would be

```
sudo ppa-purge ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo ppa-purge ppa:gnome-terminator/ppa
sudo ppa-purge ppa:pipelight/stable
```

## Method 2

You can also achieve this by using the in-built `add-apt-repository` command. This is similar to method 1.

```
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:ehoover/compholio
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:gnome-terminator/ppa
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:pipelight/stable
```

AFAIK these PPA's don't have resources for 19.10, so you'll have to wait. (I may be wrong)

Comment: You can remove PPAs using `apt-add-repository` command too. Just add `r` option, i.e. for example: `sudo apt-add-repository -r ppa:ehoover/compholio`.

Comment: not method but option